# Sunburst chart - displaying percentages of percentages

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to make a sunburst chart in excel, where the inner doughnut adds up to 100%, and the outer doughnut displays the percentages of a sub category.

I have four main categories, A=30%, B=25%, C=20%, D=25%. Which each consists of sub categories, eg A consists of A1=25% and A2=75%. I would like to display the main categories in the inner circle with their percentages and the subcategories in the outer circle with the percentages related to its main category.

I have made an example of what i am looking for here:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi welcome to SU, what part of this are you stuck with ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I should have specified it a bit more. My problem is displaying the percentages in both the inner and outer circle, i cant display the overall percentages in the inner circle, and the sub-percentages in the outer circle.

Comment: Can you post what your data set looks like, or an example ?

Comment: I believe that the problem is likely in the layout of your data. As PeterH noted, can you post a screenshot of it? It should match the picture of the chart that you posted so we can directly use it and compare etc

Comment: Hi @BBBet,, please [edit] your post & share the source data with us, will help us to understand the arrangement of data & it's categories !

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could change the label for `A`, i.e.,

```
="A "&TEXT(sum(A1, A2),"0%")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).